# proposition logic problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

below is proposition

"When A holds,  if B holds C holds, if B does not hold C also does not holds.  Regardless of B,C  if A does not hold, then D does not hold. "

Write the above sentence with a propositional formula.

$A \implies (B \implies  C)$

$A \implies ( \sim B \implies  \sim C)$

$\sim A \implies  \sim D$

Suppose that the sentence with proposition above is holds.  At this time, determine the truth of "If both C and D hold, then B holds."

is this mean i have to find :

$(A \implies  (B \implies C) \land (A \implies  ( \sim B \implies  \sim C)) \land (\sim A \implies  \sim D)) \implies  ((C \land D) \implies  B)$

is tautology or not?

I draw the table , but there is false so it means the proposition does not holds?

Comment: $(\neg A \implies \neg D)\equiv (D\implies A)$ $$$$ $$D\implies A\implies B\implies C$$ $$$$It is a tautology.

Comment: What is the line in the TT for $A,B,C,D$ entry that outputs FALSE ? Check it again...

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya but i need to find the truth value for  "If both C and D hold, then B holds." ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA do i need to find the tautology for $(A \implies  (B \implies C) \land (A \implies  ( \sim B \implies  \sim C)) \land (\sim A \implies  \sim D)) \implies  ((C \land D) \implies  B)$?

Comment: TT built-up with A,B,C,D such that : **in every line where the three premises are TRUE**, also the conclusion $(C \land D) \to B$ is TRUE.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm confuse with this statement, "Suppose that the sentence with proposition above is holds. At this time, determine the truth of "If both C and D hold, then B holds." do i have to "and" the three premises?

Comment: What @MauroALEGRANZA says cannot be more obvious: $(A\implies (B\implies C))\land(A\implies(C\implies B))\land(D\implies A)\equiv((A\implies (B\implies C\land C\implies B))\land(D\implies A))\equiv((A\implies(B\iff C))\land(D\implies A))\equiv (D\implies A\implies(B\iff C))$ $$$$ When $A$ holds: $$D\implies (B\iff C)\equiv D\implies (C\iff B)\equiv((D\implies (C\implies B))\land(D\implies( B\implies C)))$$

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya Thankyou so much for detailed explanation but i was confused , do i need to proof $(D\implies A\implies(B\iff C)) \implies  ((C \land D) \implies  B)$ is tautology or not? and also what do you mean by "when A holds" in $D\implies (B\iff C)\equiv D\implies (C\iff B)\equiv((D\implies (C\implies B))\land(D\implies( B\implies C)))$?

Comment: @kili, you have to learn, but not by heart, a few simple declarative sentences which are always useful. You can't solve problems like this until you learn the universal logic language first (: . When you understand what each of the subsentences means, you can translate a problem from the natural language into logical.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya I understood,  $D\implies (B\iff C)\equiv D\implies (C\iff B)\equiv((D\implies (C\implies B))\land(D\implies( B\implies C)))$ but i want to know why A is gone in here ? and what are you try to do ? can i use $ (D\implies A\implies ((B \implies C) \land ( C \implies B))$?

Comment: @kili, "when holds"  is redundant. It hast to be so. $$C\implies B\equiv \neg C\lor B$$ $$D\implies(C\implies D)\equiv \neg D\lor\neg C\lor B$$

Comment: @kili, the answer is a final reference to my comment. Hope it helps. If it does, you can accept my answer! Remember, use your brain, go through theory and you'll have a lot of fun!  (:

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya Thankyou but can you explain why you eliminate A? can i use $(D\implies A\implies(B\iff C))$ without eliminate A?

Comment: You can use it, I wanted to put the accent to its surrounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$C\implies B\equiv \neg C\lor B$$ 
$$D\implies(C\implies B)\equiv \neg D\lor\neg C\lor B\equiv \neg(C\land D)\lor B\equiv(C\land D)\implies B$$
We have two true sentences in your conjunction. $Q.E.D.$
Edited:
This is the final step following my last statement in comments, but the core of the problem is here:
Looking at $A$ I wrote has to hold necessarily (**transitivity of the implication**)
@kili asked for an explanation when rewriting the implication using $\lor\;\&\;\land$. In that case, it appears, the conjunction has to be true (read more on ***CNF & DNF***), it can be checked by plugging into all the truth values $1,0$ for each of the subsentences.

Comment: Thankyou so much, i understood but why do you eliminate A?

Comment: If that's confusing, put $A$, it has to be true because the implications are chained.

Comment: sorry it should be $ \neg D \lor A \lor \neg C \lor B $ , thankyou so much! but when solving this problem, is it better to use truth table or change the proposition until it is same with conclusion ?

Comment: i count once again , $D \implies A \implies (C \implies B)  \equiv ( \neg D \lor A ) \implies (\neg C \lor B) \equiv (D \land \neg A \lor \neg C\lor B \equiv (D \lor \neg C \lor B) \land (\neg A \lor \neg C \lor B)$ ,

Comment: here why i got $D \lor \neg C \lor B$ ? and its not equivalent to $C \land D \implies B$

Comment: Of course it isn't.

Comment: So should i include A or not? and why is the the answer for both quite different? is it because i was wrong when parsing ?

Comment: You have a CONJUCTION, you can't just take one sentence! Be careful.  $\tau(C)=\tau(D)=\top\implies\tau(A)=\tau(B)=\tau(C)=\tau(D)=\top$ $$\neg D\lor\neg C\lor B\equiv(C\land D)\implies B$$ beacuse: $$(\neg C\lor B)\land(\neg D\lor B)\equiv(C\implies B)\land(D\implies B)\equiv(C\land D)\implies B$$

Comment: but i cant get $\neg C \lor \neg D \lor B$ like yours , $D \implies A \implies (C \implies B \land B \implies C)  \equiv D \implies A  \implies (\neg C \lor B \land \neg B \lor C) \equiv (D \implies A \implies (\neg C \land \neg B \lor C \lor B \land \neg B \lor C \equiv (D \implies  A \implies (\neg C \land \neg B \lor C \lor F \lor C) \equiv (D \implies A \implies (\neg C \lor C \lor F )\land (\neg B \lor C \lor F) \equiv (D \land \neg A) \lor ( \neg B \lor C \lor F) \equiv (D \lor \neg B \lor C \lor F \land \neg A \lor \neg B \lor C \lor F$

Comment: can you change your answer and use A in it?

Answer (score 1):

We have to check whether the premises [entail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Proofs_and_models) the conclusion, i.e.

> $A ⟹ (B ⟹ C), A ⟹ (\lnot B ⟹ \lnot C), \lnot A ⟹ \lnot D \vDash (C \land D) ⟹ B$

which is the same as checking whether:

> $(A ⟹ (B ⟹ C)) \land (A ⟹ (\lnot B ⟹ \lnot C)) \land( \lnot A ⟹ \lnot D) ⟹ ((C \land D) ⟹ B)$

is a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Definition_and_examples).

We can avoid the full Truth Table development considering the following approach: assume not, i.e. assume that the conclusion is FALSE and the premises are all TRUE.

In order for the conclusion: $(C \land D) ⟹ B$ to be false, we must have a line in the TT where:

> $C$ and $D$ are both TRUE and $B$ is FALSE.

What happens to the premises with this line of the TT ?

With $D$ TRUE we must have also $A$ TRUE, in order to satisfy the third premise: $\lnot A ⟹ \lnot D$.

Finally, what happens to 1st and 2nd premises with $A$ TRUE ?

Consider 1st one: $A ⟹ (B ⟹ C)$. We have that $A$ and $B$ are TRUE while $C$ is FALSE. This means: $\top ⟹ (\top ⟹ \bot)$ which is FALSE, and this contradicts our assumption that all premises are TRUE.

> *Conclusion*: the assumption that the formula is **not** a *tautology* led us to a contradiction, and thus the formula **must** be a tautology.

Comment: Thankyou so much. i want to ask one more thing, if $(A ⟹ (B ⟹ C)) \land (A ⟹ (\lnot B ⟹ \lnot C)) \land( \lnot A ⟹ \lnot D) $ is tatuology then we can derive$ ((C \land D) ⟹ B)$ from $(A ⟹ (B ⟹ C)) \land (A ⟹ (\lnot B ⟹ \lnot C)) \land( \lnot A ⟹ \lnot D) $ right?

Comment: Here also you trying to proof that implication only false when premise T and conclusion false, because the result is contradiction then it always true? so it is tautology

Comment: @kili - yes, you can read my proof also that way; assume that the formula is not TAUT. This means that we have a row in the TT where the consequent $(C \land D) \to B$ is False and the antecedent is True. But this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You have :

(1) A --> ( B --> C)

(2) A --> ( ~B --> ~C)

(3) ~ A --> ~ D

The goal is : ( C & D) --> B

So, let's suppose (C & D) is true, and let's try to derive that B is true.

- If ( C& D) is true, then, in particular, D is true. But, by contraposition, (3) is equivalent to (D --> A) ( once one has applied double negation). From D and ( D -->A) one can derive that A is true ( by modus ponens).
- Now, since A is true, using (2) , it follows that ( ~B --> ~C) is true. Using contraposition ( and double negation) this is equivalent to ( C --> B) .
- But from our initial hypothesis ( namely: C&D) it follows that C is true.
- From (C -->B) and C, it follows that B is true, as desired.
- The conditional proof rule allows us to say that : (C&D) implies B.